# Calculating ROC curve for two gaussian distributions with equal variance

Tags: classification, normal-distribution, roc, signal-detection

I recall a simple formula in a paper which relates the distance between two gaussian distributions (what psychologists refer to as d') to the ROC curve under the assumption that both distributions have equal variance. I would like to know what that is.

Also is there a simple approximation for the ROC curve for when the variances are not equal?